# linq to sql where in

Tags: linq-to-sql

I want to translate query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Product WHERE Product.ID in (SELECT Product.ID FROM other_table)
```

into LINQ. I read about using the contains method but the problem is that it generates a lot of parameters for each id passed in like this:

```
WHERE [Product].[ID] IN (@p0, @p1)
```

If I had for example one bilion parameters I want to pass into my query the server won't be able to execute such a long query. Is it possible to create LINQ query in such a way that the generated SQL will be close to the original?

Thanks,
Romek

Comment: Are you against using a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using large tables then `IN` statments are a bad idea, they are very slow. You should be doing [joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).

Anyway, here is what you want;

```
using(dbDataContext db = new dbDataContext())
{
var result = from p in db.products
             join o in db.other_table
             on p.ID equals o.ID
             select p;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks - unfortunately I cannot use this approach. Sorry I wasn't so clear about what I want to achieve. Generally I want to select products from one table with a given IDs. The list of id's will came from code (generated in C# as a result of some user operations). I don't know whether this is even possible to achieve.

Comment: Why would that prevent you from performing a join?  If you only need to select rows with a certain id you don't need a join at all, just select them.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use join for this.

```
other_Table.Join(product, ot => ot.Id, pd => pd.Id, (pd, ot) => pd);
```